# How to fix ‘The ROI line position counter’ wrong result in Python counting object project

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to re-customize this code specifically as ROI line in the main function but when the object passes, it cannot be counted. I think the error is where I set the ROI line but I didn't find the error. Please help everyone. Thank you everyone.

my main: http://codepad.org/9PnDX2th
my function: http://codepad.org/zHPVe3nW

Comment: Please include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example in your question rather than links to external sites.

Comment: sorry, the code so long so I think it's would better to be upload on codepad for easy to read.